# Jquery all ajax calls not picking relative url - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    getDefaultPDF();
    loadPDF();   
});

function loadPDF() {
    $('#reportsDiv').load("/Review/DisplayPdfPartial");
}
```

Our site is hosted under the Default website, within a folder. So the url should be
http://servername/foldername/Review/DisplayPdfPartial

but the following code tries to fetch
http://servername/Review/DisplayPdfPartial - doesn't add the foldername and fails obviously.

This doesn't happen on local, only when deployed under default website.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned you are using Asp.Net MVC then in that case instead of specifying url's this way, a more efficient way is to use `@Url.Action()` helper method as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getDefaultPDF();
    loadPDF();   
});

function loadPDF() {
    //$('#reportsDiv').load("/Review/DisplayPdfPartial");
    $('#reportsDiv').load('@Url.Action("DisplayPdfPartial","Review")');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ResolveClientUrl`

> A fully qualified URL to the specified resource suitable for use on
>   the browser.
>
> Use the ResolveClientUrl method to return a URL string suitable for
>   use by the client to access resources on the Web server, such as image
>   files, links to additional pages, and so on

.